# AS3 Selecting movieclips by base class

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, class, movieclip

I want to add movieclips which are instances of a certain class to an array (only add movie clips which are instances of BLAH). I can't find any property which refers to the movieclip's class. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Use `is` operator:

```
if( mc is BLAH){
   // here you are
}
```

From [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is):

> Evaluates whether an object is compatible with a specific data type,
>   class, or interface

Comment: Just to expand on this: if the instance is a subclass of BLAH, it will also return `true`.

Comment: @Pier yep , once BLAH - always BLAH